# PHP & JavaScript sign up page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

It is very difficult to explain this; I don't see why my code works when I take one line out but when I put it back in it don't work.

```
if($u == "" || $fn == "" || $e == "" || $p == "" || $g == "" || $c == "")
```

As soon as I take out `$fn == "" ||` it works. It is strange as the whole code works apart from that.

Here is the website https://studentnet.kingston.ac.uk/k1003140/signup.php

Comment: may be use trim($fn) == "" ?

Comment: Why don't you print out $fn and see what's going out with it.

Comment: Is $fn variable setted? Check it with isset() function

Comment: I tried printing out $fn nothing came up, and i also tried $u to see what prints out nothing happens

Comment: please code were you are assigning values to these varaibles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(isset($u) && isset($fn) && isset($e) && isset($p) && isset($g) && isset($c))
{
        if(empty($u) || empty($fn) || empty($e) || empty($p) || empty($g) || empty($c))
        {
            // it work when at least one of them is Empty 
            // AND ALL OF THEM SETED
        }

}
```

Comment: or one them not set, I think $fn is not set in your program that why when you removed your code work

Comment: and you say in your comment when try to printing $fn nothing happen, I think you should set all variables at first line of your program and then try to run this block of code

Comment: all the variable are set here  `$u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
 $fn = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['fn']);`

Comment: thats only the two but one with $u works the other dont.

Answer (score 1):

Dump the variables and see what's coming through. Also, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: I tried that and nothing came up so I guess it's fine